# git revert isn't working the way I expect it to

Tags: git

I add 1 empty file called `1.js`. I save this commit to my local repository as "one".

I add 1 empty file called `2.js`. I save this commit as "two".

I add 1 empty file called `3.js`. I save this commit as "three".

When I do `git revert twoRefNumber`, I expect the working directory to show just `1.js` & `3.js`. (Is this what I should expect?).

Instead, I get this error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't confirm this behavior. I've made the same test that you did and revert has created another commit that deleted 2.js. So it works as you were expecting.

Revert is an another commit that you'll see in the history (for example git log should show 4 commits)

This is how it looks on my pc after running `git revert 032ae782fba81f5a75a77468f0511ea7ef7a278b`:

```
commit 5092c16542beb30b581553cde69edd6602cff3c8 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Mark Bramnik <my-email>
Date:   Thu Oct 22 17:51:02 2020 +0300

    Revert "two"

    This reverts commit 032ae782fba81f5a75a77468f0511ea7ef7a278b.

commit deb29a67891b8c36a6e2a960b968696e8a45a49a
Author: Mark Bramnik <my-email>
Date:   Thu Oct 22 17:50:47 2020 +0300

    three

commit 032ae782fba81f5a75a77468f0511ea7ef7a278b
Author: Mark Bramnik <my-email>
Date:   Thu Oct 22 17:50:35 2020 +0300

    two

commit cf58b23516832733db2bc1cc1fd33c1dd5d33b1d
Author: Mark Bramnik <my-email>
Date:   Thu Oct 22 17:50:26 2020 +0300

    one
```

Since the actual actions that revert commit should take are calculated by git automatically the chances are that you indeed have some conflict, maybe you've happened to change 2.js later or something. In any case you can type `git status` and see what exactly git "thinks" is wrong and it will answer the question of what happens...

Comment: sorry to waste your time I was actually copy & pasting the wrong commit reference number. Do you recommend I delete the post?

Comment: Question is a question, and it deserves to be answered, no worries about the time. As for deleting the question - as you wish, your are the "question owner" :)